# Is there a way to use one of the apply functions in R to optimise this loop?

Tags: r, loops, apply

I've got the following two data frames in R:

```
> head(gene)

    V1        V2 V3
1 chr2 178525989 10
2 chr2 178525990 10
3 chr2 178525991 10
4 chr2 178525992 10
5 chr2 178525993 10
6 chr2 178525994 10

> head(exons)

    V1  V2          V3        V4        V5 V6 V7 V8  V9
1 chr2 lrg exonic_part 178807212 178807423  .  -  . 001
2 chr2 lrg exonic_part 178804552 178804655  .  -  . 002
3 chr2 lrg exonic_part 178802138 178802341  .  -  . 003
4 chr2 lrg exonic_part 178800395 178800682  .  -  . 004
5 chr2 lrg exonic_part 178799825 178799910  .  -  . 005
6 chr2 lrg exonic_part 178799487 178799731  .  -  . 006
```

Each of the pairs in `exons$V4` and `exons$V5` denote the start and end of a range. There are 364 rows and therefore 364 such pairs in `exons`.

What I need to do is go through every element of `gene$V2` and check if it is included in any of these ranges in `exons`. If it is included I need to add an entry of "exon" into another vector, and if it's excluded I need to add an entry of "intron" into that vector.

So, for example, if the first three elements of `gene$V2` were included in at least one range, and the next three were not, I would expect to get a vector like this:

```
> include_exclude[1:6]
[1] "exon" "exon" "exon" "intron" "intron" "intron"
```

At the moment I'm doing this using the `inside.range()` function from `spatstat.utils` which takes as input one or more values to check (`x`) and one range (`r`), and outputs `TRUE` if in range and `FALSE` if out of range. I'm using it with a loop within a loop:

```
include_exclude <- c()
for (i in 1:dim(gene)[1]){
        list <- c()
        for (x in 1:dim(exons)) {
                list <- c(list,inside.range(as.numeric(gene$V2[i]),as.numeric(exons[x,4:5])))
        }
        if (sum(list) > 0) {include_exclude <- c(include_exclude, "exon")}
        else {include_exclude <- c(include_exclude, "intron")}
        print(i) #to see how far along the loop is
}
```

However, this is obviously an extremely inefficient way of going about this. I suspect there's a much more efficient approach using one of the `apply` functions in R, but I've never really understood them and can't quite figure out how to use them in this setting. Can someone please help?

Thanks!

Comment: It would help if your sample data actually had any matches in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This returns if each of your `gene$V2` are within at least one of the ranges in `exons$V4` to `$V5`.

```r
sapply(gene$V2, function(v) any(exons$V4 <= v & v <= exons$V5, na.rm = TRUE))
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

It's easy enough to convert this into `"exon"` or `"intron"` (using `ifelse`, `dplyr::if_else`, `data.table::fifelse` or perhaps just a vector lookup), as in

```r
rets <- sapply(gene$V2, function(v) any(exons$V4 <= v & v <= exons$V5, na.rm = TRUE))
ifelse(rets, "exon", "intron")
# [1] "intron" "intron" "intron" "intron" "intron" "intron"
c("intron", "exon")[ 1 + rets ]
# [1] "intron" "intron" "intron" "intron" "intron" "intron"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a sequence between `V4` and `V5` columns using `Map` and check if any of the value is present in `gene$V2` and assign the value accordingly.

```
all_sequence <- unique(unlist(Map(`:`, exons$V4, exons$V5)))
gene$include_exclude <- ifelse(gene$V2 %in% all_sequence, 'exon', 'intron')
```

Using `ifelse` is easy to understand however, you can do this without `ifelse` as well.

```
gene$include_exclude <- c('intron', 'exon')[(gene$V2 %in% all_sequence) + 1]
```